# Spring WebFlux: Perform multiple mappings on the same object?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-webflux

I'm currently making my first ever reactive project with Spring WebFlux. Unfortunately, I already got a task assigned that I cannot seem to find a solution for.
I would like to receive a Mono and perform operations on it, depending on what other Monos complete. My idea goes like this:

```
private Mono<ResourceModel> setResourcesIfExisting(String resourceName) {
        
        return resourceService.findByFilter(resourceName)
                .flatMap(res -> service1.findByFilter(resourceName).map(res::setResource))
                .flatMap(res -> service2.findByFilter(resourceName).map(res::setResource))
                .flatMap(res -> service3.findByFilter(resourceName).map(res::setResource))
                ;
    }
```

A Mono will be found by the resourceService, note that this is already the same type that I want to return. But now, I have some other services that deliver resources and in therory there should be exactly one fulfilling resource mono across all of those services.
From my tests, it always works if I use one of those flatMaps but as soon as I have two or more consecutively the list that gets collected on the higher level method results empty (I am using the above method for each element of a `Flux<String>`).

Would someone be able to give me a pointed why this happens? As said above, I barely understand what I'm doing but tried out a lot with no success so far.

Comment: i dont really understand your question `in therory there should be exactly one fulfilling resource mono across all of those services` what do you mean by `fulfilling`. `but as soon as I have two or more` im guessing you mean two or more `flatMaps`?

`flatMap` will take an item, and then return that item as a `Mono<T>` to the next `flatMap` in the chain. I think it would be better if you expanded your example and provided code that explains what all these `service1.findByFilter` do and what `res.setResource` do. What your intentions are.

Comment: its very hard to give you any pointers when we dont have a fully running example.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I meant one `Mono` that acutally holds a value as a `Mono` can only contain one object maximum. Sorry if this is an incorrect term. Basically I expect exactly one of either `service1`, `service2` or `service3` to return one value.
Yes, that 'two or more' meant two or more `flatMap`s.
The 'findByFilter' methods each return a model that they obtain from the database and the 'setResource' methods are basic setters. They are intended to set the model that they received into the respective variable into the `ResourceModel` that comes from `resourceService`.

Comment: well `map` and `flatMap` needs a return value. Reactive programming fetches a lot of its fundamentals from functional programming, which means that mutability is to be avoided. Which means that manipulating created objects by using setters is not something you should do, as it will give you a lot of problems. So as i dont have the full picture of your code its hard to actually give you any advice, but you need to pass your `res` class through the flatMaps if you want to mutate it. Which also means that after you have fetched new data, you need to pass on the `res` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the mentioned output is due to this.

- Let's assume you gets `Mono<ResourceModel>` from `resourceService.findByFilter(resourceName)` which is not **empty**.
- But after the first `.flatmap` by calling `service1.findByFilter(resourceName)` it may return **empty**.
- After returning empty, other `flatmap` s are not called as no element will be returned as `flatmap` is called upon each element.

Alternatively you can use the following to achieve what you expected

```java
private Mono<ResourceModel> setResourcesIfExisting(String resourceName) {

    return resourceService.findByFilter(resourceName)
            .flatMap(res -> service1.findByFilter(resourceName)
                    .switchIfEmpty(service2.findByFilter(resourceName))
                    .switchIfEmpty(service3.findByFilter(resourceName))
                    .doOnEach(stringSignal -> res.setResource(stringSignal.get()))
                    .thenReturn(res));
}
```

`thenReturn` will return the `ResourceModel` even if all the service1,2,3 return empty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was not needed anymore because this was asked a longer time ago but I'm sure that this is exactly what I needed back then. If I ever come into a similiar situation I look forward to use this!